# Using two buttons in the same form

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to use two buttons on the same form, one is to upload a file an the other button is to submit a form, The first one show the drop down to select a file and then calls the action of the post method. How do I seperate the functions of the two buttons?

Html

```
<div data-role="content" class="jqm-content">    
    <div class="jqm-home-welcome">
        <h2>Pleasurable</h2>
        <p class="ui-li-desc"> A place for all the good times</p>
        <form method="post" action="addsoothing" enctype="multipart/form-data"> 
            <button onclick="submitForm('addpic')">Click to Add pic</button>
            <output id="list"></output>    
            <input id="uploadImage" type="file" />
            <button onclick="submitForm('uploadimage')" id="files">Upload image</button>
        </form>    
    </div>     
</div>
```

JavaScript

```
<script>
    function submitForm(button) {
        if (button == 'addpic') {
            document.getElementById('uploadImage').click();
        } else if (button == 'uploadimage') {
            document.getElementById('files').addEventListener('change', handleFileSelect, false).click();
        }

        document.getElementById.submit();
    }

    if (window.FileReader) {
        function handleFileSelect(evt) {
            var files = evt.target.files;
            var f = files[0];
            var reader = new FileReader();

            reader.onload = (function(theFile) {
                return function(e) {
                    document.getElementById('list').innerHTML = ['<img src="', e.target.result, '" title="', theFile.name, '" width="50"/>'].join('');
                };
            })(f);

            reader.readAsDataURL(f);
        }
    } else {
        alert('This browser does not support FileReader');
    }


</script>
```

Comment: And the question is ?

Comment: What's the problem or question?

Comment: Well, you updated with a question, but it's very unclear. You should take some time and explain very clearly what you're asking about. I have no idea what *"seperate the functions of the two buttons"* means.

Comment: The questions is how do I seperate the functions of the two buttons as my solution is not working properly?

Comment: Please describe "not working properly." Are you getting errors?

Comment: I am not getting errors bascially the first button does the job of the two together, the first button calls the function of the second button after selection is complete which is not what I want. I want one button to select a file and the other to submit the form

Comment: Just add a button type to the image button and it won't submit the form http://jsfiddle.net/f9sE6/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure I fully understand the question, but I THINK you're asking how to tie a different function to each button. If that's what you're asking, then the answer is as simple as just assigning a different function call in the onclick handler of one of the buttons. Instead of one submitForm() function, write two functions... One called selectFile() and one called submitForm().